# Preprocessor expected - MS Visual / C++

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

I'm just trying to use MS Visual for some really simple C++ coding for school purposes. The point is I can't even write a simple hello-world alike program.
I've got that error "Preprocessor expected" in line with library. Line with code looks like this: `#include <iostream>`

Any help with solving this (probably) minor problem is welcomed.

Here is whole code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "aogaohgo";
}
```

Comment: I somehow doubt that "Preprocessor expected" is really the error message. I've never seen it, it doesn't make sense and the only Google result for it is this question or refers to it.

Comment: Your code is 100% perfect. You are invoking your compiler in a wrong way. Or (much less likely) it is installed in a very wrong way. How do you invoke the compiler?

Comment: @ChristianHackl Or OP is invoking the wrong compiler. That's almost a C# error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OP's reported error message is reminiscent of a C# error message.

Testing this theory and pasting OPs C++ code into a C# console project I receive:

```
error CS1024: Preprocessor directive expected
```

As the first error.

Solution: Create a new project and make sure the selected language is C++

Answer (score 0):

`#include` isn't valid on it's own.

The correct syntax is `#include <filename>`.

I suggest you pick up a better Hello World tutorial :)

Comment: The OP's posting actually says `#include <iostream>`, but he did not format it correctly and apparently ignored the preview. I just fixed it with an edit.

Comment: @ChristianHackl yeah, I noticed afterwards. weird error ¯\_(ツ)_/¯